# Drupal 8 - I cannot call a function in another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, drupal

I have two JavaScript files on my custom theme. One file has functions that need to be used on the other file. What I have below doesn't work. This is the error I get.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined.

jQuery will be used on both files.

#### file1.js

```js
/**
 * @file
 * UI behaviors
 */

(function ($, Drupal) {

 'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function () {
    function test(){
     console.log('hello'):
    }
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

#### file2.js

```js
/**
 * @file
 * UI behaviors
 */

(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).ready(function () {
     test();
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

#### customtheme.libraries.yml

```yaml
scripts:
  js:
    js/file1.js: {}
    js/file2.js: {}
```

#### customtheme.info.yml

```yaml
libraries:
 - 'customtheme/scripts'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test function is not in the global scope.
If you want your test function to be able to be called from anywhere, **don't** put it in the $(document).ready or in the IIFE.
ie. in the first file, just have..

```
function test(){
  console.log('hello);
}
```

You may also want to namespace your functions, but that is a separate question I suppose.

Also, for Drupal, you may be wanting to use drupal.behaviors rather than $(document).ready (for the second file)

Comment: Thanks for checking this out, but how would I be able to use jQuery in the first file if I get rid of  the two outer functions (`(function ($, Drupal) {`and`$(document).ready(function () {`)?

Comment: in file1 you are sending "jQuery" to the IIFE and renaming it to "$". You should just be able to use "jQuery" instead of "$" in my above answer. Make sure it is a dependency of your library though to make sure it is loaded. But personally, I would not use jQuery unless really necessary.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at some javascript tutorials to try to understand javascript variable scopes and IIFEs